# ggplot error, filter dplyr error and merging order

Tags: r, ggplot2, merge, dplyr

I have this dataframe:

```
> str(DFPA)
List of 10
$ Quest  : chr [1:1917] "2" "3" "4" "5" ...
$ PASM   : chr [1:1917] "127.5" "107" "111.5" "103" ...
$ PADM   : chr [1:1917] "85.5" "58.5" "73" "69" ...
$ PAM    : chr [1:1917] "99.5" "74.6666666666667" "85.8333333333333"       "80.3333333333333" ...
$ PP     : chr [1:1917] "42" "48.5" "38.5" "34" ...
$ Idade  : chr [1:1917] "52" "53" "47" "44" ...
$ CCor   : chr [1:1917] "B" "B" "PD" "PD" ...
$ CGI    : chr [1:1917] "3º" "3º" "3º" "3º" ...
$ Sexo   : chr [1:1917] "F" "F" "M" "M" ...
$ FEtária: chr [1:1917] "C" "C" "C" "B" ...
```

However, I was creating another 3 dataframes based on DFPA: DFPAA, DFPAB and DFPC, they have the same variables, but they are divided by Age, A(25-34 years), B(35-44), C(45-59). Then, this erros appear:

```
library(dplyr)        
 >          DFPAA <- filter(DFPA, FEtária == "A")
 Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
 no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "list"
 >          
 >          DFPAB <- filter(DFPA, FEtária == "B")
 Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
 no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "list"
 >          
 >          DFPAC <- filter(DFPA, FEtária == "C")
 Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
 no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "list"
```

I've search this erros, but the answers didnt solve the problem.

Another problem that I am having is whith merging another dataframe from SAS:

```
install.packages("memisc")

     library(memisc)

     data <- as.data.set(spss.system.file("medicamentos_fase4a_pro_saude.sav"))

     Medicamentos <- subset(data, select = c(quest, med_rec))

     View(Medicamentos)

     library(plyr)

     Med <- ddply(Medicamentos, .(quest), summarize, Rem = paste (med_rec, collapse =", "))

     names(Med)[names(Med) == 'quest'] <- 'Quest'
              DFPA <- merge (DFPA, Med, by = "Quest")
```

Then, when the merge occurs this happens:

```
 head(DFPA)
 Quest  PASM PADM              PAM   PP Idade CCor CGI Sexo FEtária
 1  1002   102 67.5               79 34.5    58   PD  2º    F       C
 2  1003    99   57               71   42    55   PD  3º    F       C
 3  1005   115   74 87.6666666666667   41    52    B  3º    F       C
 4  1006   152   91 111.333333333333   61    52   PD  2º    F       C
 5  1007 110.5   69 82.8333333333333 41.5    41   PD  3º    F       B
 6  1012   119 74.5 89.3333333333333 44.5    57    P  3º    F       C                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

 Rem
 1 ezetimiba+sinvastatina, fitoterápico, nimesulida, quitosana, vitamina
 2     cumarina+troxerrutina, ergotamina+cafeína+dipirona, oxibutinina                                                                                                                                                                                   
 3    dipirona, escopolamina                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 4        anlodipino, hidroclorotiazida, losartana, não-classificado                                                                                                                                                                                  
 5       desogestrel                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 6        anlodipino, atenolol
```

The ascending order of Quest gets completely crazy and I can't organize this.

Then, when I create a list with antihypertensive medication to exclude from the dataframe with this function:

```
     ListadeMedicamentos <- c("...", ...)
     DFPA2 <- DFPA[ !DFPA$Rem %in% ListaMedicamentosHAS, ]
```

It excludes some of the rows, but not others. Not everyone on this dataframe use drugs, so I expected that the merge could generated some NA, but it didn't, and I think that it's wrong.

Another problem that occurs when I use ggplot, this erros appear: error-discrete-value-supplied-to-continuous-scale

This is the model that I am using:

```
GSS <- ggplot(DFPA, aes(x=PASM, fill=Sexo)) + geom_density(alpha=.3)     + scale_x_continuous (name = "Pressão Arterial Sistólica Média", limits = c(86, 230)) + scale_y_continuous(name = "Probabilidade", limits = c(0, 0.06))
```

So, I have 3 problems: with the filter function, list and ggplot!

Thank you!

EDIT:

```
DFPA <- as.data.frame(DFPA)

class(DFPA)
data.frame

head(DFPA)
Quest  PASM PADM              PAM   PP Idade CCor CGI Sexo FEtária
1     2 127.5 85.5             99.5   42    52    B  3º    F       C
2     3   107 58.5 74.6666666666667 48.5    53    B  3º    F       C
3     4 111.5   73 85.8333333333333 38.5    47   PD  3º    M       C
4     5   103   69 80.3333333333333   34    44   PD  3º    M       B
5     7 112.5 72.5 85.8333333333333   40    54   PD  3º    F       C
6     8    99 62.5 74.6666666666667 36.5    54    B  2º    M       C
```

So, now I can merge the 2 dataframes and it's ok.

But, I cant create a subset of my data containing values of my column (FEtária)

```
> DFPAC <- DFPA[DFPA$FEtária == "C", ]
Error in DFPA[DFPA$FEtária == "C", ] : incorrect number of dimensions
> DFPAc <- subset(DFPA, FEtária == "C")
> View(DFPAC)
Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1917, 0
> sel <- apply(DFPA[,FEtária],1,function(row) length(grep("C",row))>0)
Error in DFPA[, FEtária] : incorrect number of dimensions
> 
> class(FEtária)
[1] "factor"
> DFPAC <- subset(DFPA, grepl("C", DFPA$FEtária))
> 
> View(DFPAC)
Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1917, 0
> DFPAC <- DFPA[grep("C", DFPA$FEtária), ]
Error in DFPA[grep("C", DFPA$FEtária), ] : incorrect number of dimensions
> class(DFPA)
[1] "list"
> DFPA <- as.data.frame(DFPA)
> > DFPAC <- DFPA[grep("C", DFPA$FEtária), ]
Error: unexpected '>' in ">"
> 
> DFPAC <- DFPA[grep("C", DFPA$FEtária), ]
> 
> View(DFPAc)
Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1917, 0
```

I cant figure out how to exclude the rows that contain the same "value" in the list. The grepl() didnt work:

```
> Med <- Med[!grepl(ListadeMedicamentosHAS, Med$Rem), ]
Error in Med[!grepl(ListadeMedicamentosHAS, Med$Rem), ] : 
incorrect number of dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In grepl(ListadeMedicamentosHAS, Med$Rem) :
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

> DFPAC <- filter(DFPA, !grepl("ListadeMedicamentosHAS"))
Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : 
argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I think my post is extremely confusing, so I'll try to simplify it: I have DFPA, then I need to subset it based in "FEtária", which has 3 values (A, B and C). Concurrent to that, I need to exclude all the hypertensive medications that are in "ListadeMedicamentos" from DFPA, that I've correctly merged now, with your help!

Thank you, guys!

Comment: For the first point, you do not have a `data.frame`, it is a `list`.

Comment: The data you have is a `list` like Nick suggested. Could you please convert the `list` to `data.frame` and post also your sample data.

Comment: Shure, I will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Another problem that occurs when I use ggplot, this erros appear:
>   error-discrete-value-supplied-to-continuous-scale

`DFPA$PASM` must be numeric, but it is now character or factor. If it's just plain numbers imported as text, you can use `as.numeric(DFPA$PASM)`, but afterwards make sure the data looks as you expect it to do (i.e. check whether the range and distribution are reasonable).

> The ascending order of Quest gets completely crazy and I can't organize this.

Merging works by sorting the key variable. Just sort the merged dataframe in whatever order you want after merging.

> Then, when I create a list with antihypertensive medication to exclude
>   from the dataframe with this function:
>
> ```
>  ListadeMedicamentos <- c("...", ...)
>  DFPA2 <- DFPA[ !DFPA$Rem %in% ListaMedicamentosHAS, ]
> ```
>
> It excludes some of the rows, but not others.

`%in%` checks whether any elements match exactly, and does not look inside the strings. `"a" %in% c("aaa", "a + a", "a ")` will return `FALSE`. If you want to keep lists of medications as concatenated strings, read on `grep` in R.

> Not everyone on this dataframe use drugs, so I expected that the merge could generated some NA, but it didn't, and I think that it's wrong.

`merge` by default corresponds to an `INNER JOIN` from database operations: only rows present in both input dataframes are maintained. If you want to keep the other rows as well, check out the `all, all.x, all.y` options in `?merge`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I could correctly merged, but I couldnt resolve the other 2 problems: subsetting and excluding rows that contain the antihypertensive medication.

Comment: Excluding rows will require a loop, because `grepl` looks up only one pattern at a time. Something like `for(m in listedMeds){ DF = DF[ !grepl(m, DF$Rem), ] }`. The subsetting should have worked, though - maybe you have overwritten your dataframe before? Try reloading R, and if it still doesn't work, provide the output of `str(DFPA)` and just `DFPA$Fetária=="C"`. (Btw, avoid using fancy symbols like á or ° in data.)

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I could manage all the problemas, but another appeared:

When I use ggplot, the following error appears: 
Removed 9 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density).
But I dont have negative values, and I've checked the xlim and compare to the dataframe and the range is right, however when I use max(PP) a value that is not in the dataframe appears, and it's bigger than the others.

Comment: ``> str(DFPA)
'data.frame': 1126 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Quest  : Factor w/ 1918 levels "10","100","1000",..: 5 6 8 9 10 18 19 20 21 26 ...
 $ PASM   : Factor w/ 177 levels "100","100.5",..: 5 176 31 105 22 59 68 166 26 4 ...
 $ PADM   : Factor w/ 122 levels "100","100.5",..: 59 38 72 106 62 107 76 44 71 56 ...
 $ PAM    : Factor w/ 338 levels "100","100.166666666667",..: 213 165 265 67 236 25 310 167 258 206 ...
 $ PP     : Factor w/ 114 levels "100.5","19","24.5",..: 22 37 35 75 36 28 68 21 31 24 ...``

Comment: ``$ Idade  : Factor w/ 35 levels "25","26","27",..: 34 31 28 28 17 35 35 18 20 27 ...
 $ CCor   : Factor w/ 3 levels "B","P","PD": 3 3 1 3 3 3 1 3 1 1 ...
 $ CGI    : Factor w/ 3 levels "1º","2º","3º": 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 ...
 $ Sexo   : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ FEtária: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 ...
 $ Rem    : chr  "ezetimiba+sinvastatina, fitoterápico, nimesulida, quitosana, vitamina e suplemento mineral, vitamina e suplemento mineral, vita"...``

Comment: @RafaelvonHellmann any new problems should be moved to separate questions, so that the answer & discussion might be useful for the community as well, not only for you. To answer in short, do not use factors for numeric variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `as.integer` with a `sleep` condition in the loop. However, this does not guarantee that your process will take place every other second as some loops might take longer time depending on cpu allocation an other circumstances. The following code, does almost meet your requirements. As you will notice sometimes the process skips two seconds instead of one.

```
i=1
df=NULL
while (i <= 10)
{
   p1 <- proc.time()
   system_time <- Sys.time()
   if (as.integer(system_time)%%2 == 0)
   {
          if(is.null(df))
          {
              df <- system_time
          }else{
              df <- rbind(df, system_time)
          }
         i = i + 1
       }
       Sys.sleep(abs(1- (proc.time() - p1)))
}
```

The output is :

```
> df
               [,1]
df          1490062164
system_time 1490062166
system_time 1490062168
system_time 1490062170
system_time 1490062172
system_time 1490062174
system_time 1490062176
system_time 1490062178
system_time 1490062180
system_time 1490062182
```